# PyCharm, installed as a snap, keeps stating "Python Debugger Extension Available" every time the debugger is started

Tags: python, snap, pycharm

**Setup**:

Snap-Version of PyCharm (installed with --classic, as in the [installation instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installation-guide.html#standalone))

**Problem**:

Every time I start the debugger in PyCharm a popup stating "Python Debugger Extension Available" shows up.

Clickling on "install" produces a log entry that the extension was built, but restarting the debugger shows the same popup again.

The extension can be found under `/home/user/.cache/JetBrains/PyCharm2021.1/cythonExtensions` but is apparently not used by PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question, since I did not find a solution to my specific problem.

Most of the time the problem is a missing C-Compiler or people trying to build the extension manually into the snap which is read-only.
But I did not find a solution to when the extension was built, but not found.

My specific problem was, that I was using the .env plugin in the run configuration to set environment variables from a file.
Inside that file I was setting the `PYTHONPATH`.

Apparently PyCharm adds the path to the extension `/home/XXX/.cache/JetBrains/PyCharm2021.1/cythonExtensions` to the `PYTHONPATH` which is then overwritten by the plugin.

So if the extension is built (there is a `_pydevd_bundle_ext` and a `_pydevd_frame_eval_ext` folder under `cythonExtensions`) but not used, make sure that the extension directory is in the `PYTHONPATH`.